# Error message "make sure that 'gem install oj -v'3.1.3' succeeds before bundling"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting an error like:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/oj-3.1.3/ext/oj
C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20170616-5396-19dncaf.rb extconf.rb
Creating Makefile for ruby version 2.3.0 on x64-mingw32 

creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/oj-3.1.3/ext/oj
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/oj-3.1.3/ext/oj
make "DESTDIR="
generating oj-x64-mingw32.def
compiling cache8.c
make: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: Command not found
make: *** [cache8.o] Error 127

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/oj-3.1.3 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.3.0/oj-3.1.3/gem_make
.out

An error occurred while installing oj (3.1.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install oj -v '3.1.3'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  oj
```

Ruby version -2.3.0
Rails version -4.2.3
windows 7

Comment: Yeah, so did you make sure of that?

Comment: yes, i did no fix found yet

Comment: If you did make sure of that, then bundle install would have succeeded. What exactly did you do after seeing this error?

Comment: i have done gem install oj -v' '3.1.3'

Comment: i just cloned application repository from git, and while installing and runnung that application i got this error

Comment: i just cloned application repository from github. and while installing and running that appliaction by rails s and bundle install i got this error i also tried gem install oj-v'3.1.3' to resolve this error.